# Constructor DI - Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following code:

```
private IMemoryCache _cache;

public HomeController(IMemoryCache memoryCache) : base() {    
   this._cache = memoryCache;    
}
```

`ASP.Net Core` is handling the injection of the `IMemoryCache` instance via:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
   services.AddMemoryCache();
}
```

It is flagging the `_cache` field with:

> Field HomeController._cache is never assigned to, and will always have
>   its default value null

It's not causing any errors, it is just distracting in the editor.

What is the way to go about convincing Visual Studio 2017 that I am in fact assigning this field a value, via the constructor?

Code (because the error overlaps it):

[image]

With the editor showing the error:

[image]

At runtime showing the valid instance being injected:

[image]

**Edit:**

For the comments suggesting to use:

```
private IMemoryCache _cache = null;
```

... this makes no difference, same exact result.

Comment: Okay where you are calling the HomeController constructor with IMemoryCache parameter.

Comment: You could assign null when it is declared `private IMemoryCache _cache = null` this should remove the warning

Comment: @mybirthname .Net Core handles this automatically.  I have verified the constructor is being called, the parameter has a valid non-null instance, and the caching code in the MVC action method which uses this._cache is also working as expected.

Comment: @JaimeMacias I have tried that, same result.

Comment: I seriously doubt the code shown in the post can trigger this warning. Please make sure what you have as sample of `HomeController` is actually [MCVE] for the error (and it should have absolutely nothing to do with DI).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Screenshots added, because I wouldn't believe it either.

Comment: Simply initialize it with null. It's code analysis rule showing the warning you can either suppress it using CA attribute or turn it off globally in Visual studio. Editor doesn't know if you have setup the container to inject the dependency which is why you are seeing the warning.

Comment: Do you have any other constructors overloads defined that don't assign `_cache`?

Comment: @RichardSzalay No that is the only constructor.

Comment: It looks more like some extension (like an outdated ReSharper version) is being used here. Visual Studio 2017 doesn't produce this kind of errors/warnings iirc

Comment: @Tseng No extensions like Resharper but I just "fixed" this by installing Visual Studio 2017 update version 15.3.3 which I was just notified about.  Re-starting Visual Studio did not fix it, but installing the update did.  I doubt the update "fixed" anything, probably something in my installation got a little screwy and the update resolved it.

Comment: Odd. I only know it from ReSharper & Co which would change the color of the variable, when there is an error

Comment: @Tseng I do use SemanticColorizer which simply changes the editor colors semantically based on Roslyn, but wouldn't interfere with this aspect of the IDE's error/warning detection.   Good catch though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio 2017 and rebooting did not resolve the issue.

However, I was notified of Visual Studio 2017 update version **15.3.3** when the environment reloaded, which I installed.

After re-starting Visual Studio post-update, this situation is no longer occurring.

I doubt the update actually did anything related to this problem, it's more likely something in my VS configuration was off and the update put things back in place.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case on VS2015. In my case `Build -> Rebuild Solution` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning your solution should solve this. In VS2017 menus: `Project -> Clean Solution`.